# Fit imported image in panel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser

I tried importing image via `JFileChooser` into `JPanel`. It worked. but I need to fit the image inside the panel without losing its aspect ratio or its proportion.

I tried rescaling the image, here's my code:

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(picture.getSource());
Image scaledImage = img.getScaledInstance(jPanel1.getWidth(),jPanel1.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

g2.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0,null,null);
```

But unable to protect its ratio. I need a simple code for this.

Comment: You might like to have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008507/how-to-make-bmp-fills-the-jpanel/12008809#12008809 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485435/scalable-images-in-java/12486410#12486410 all of which discuss image resizing while maintain the aspect ratio and the perils of the `getSclaedInstance` method

Answer (score 5):

Try reading [the instructions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> If either width or height is a negative number then a value is substituted to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image dimensions. If both width and height are negative, then the original image dimensions are used.

Comment: READ THE MANUAL! We are men, we don't need manuals, that's why we have hospitals... +1 however...

Comment: isnt there any simple method for this?